# why is $1/n \sum_{i} (X_i -10)^2$ unbiased

Tags: estimation, bias, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Let $\{ X_1,X_2,...,X_n \}$ be n observations randomly drawn from normal distribution with mean  $10$ and unknown variance. Prove that the estimator $1/n \sum_{i} (X_i -10)^2$ is unbiased.
Why is this estimator unbiased? Isn't we've proved that only $1/(n-1) \sum_{i} (X_i -10)^2$ is unbiased?

Comment: No, you proved that $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i (X_i-\bar{x})^2$ is unbiased. $\bar{x}$ is closer to the data than $\mu$ is, so you need to divide by a smaller quantity

Comment: It's clearly an unbiased statistic for the population parameter $E((1/n)\sum (X_i-10)^2)$.  They didn't ask if it was an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.  On the other hand, it isn't an unbiased estimator of lots of other parameters,for instance, $\sigma$, kurtosis, etc.         :)

Answer (score 5):

If $X_i \sim \mathcal N(10, \sigma^2)$, then
$Y_i := X_i - 10 \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$.
Thus $$\mathbb E[(X_i - 10)^2] = \mathbb E[Y_i^2] = \mathrm{Var}(Y_i) + \mathbb E[ Y_i]^2 = \sigma^2,$$ so by linearity of expectation $$\mathbb E\left[\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - 10)^2\right] = \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma^2 = \sigma^2.$$

Because you know the mean, you don't have to do the Bessel correction of dividing by $N-1$, and in fact that would bias your estimator.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse $\displaystyle \frac1{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i - \overline X \right)^2$ with $\displaystyle \frac1{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i - 10 \right)^2.$

If you take a new sample of $n$ observations independent of the first $n$, then $\overline X$ will change but $10$ will not change. They're two different things.

And it is far easier to prove that $\displaystyle \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i - 10 \right)^2$ is unbiased then that $\displaystyle \frac1{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i - \overline X \right)^2$ is unbiased (but both are unbiased).